# Text must be rendered within <Text> Component

Tags: react-native

While looking around at other questions, I still seemed to not be able to solve my issue. It still believes that there is text somewhere and I just need to know if I am completely overlooking something. I am new to React Native and React.js as a whole.

``

```
<View style={styles.body}>
  {restaurantData.length ? (
      <Text>{restaurantData.length}</Text>
   ) : null}
  {restaurantData ? (
      <View>
            {restaurantData.map((restaurant) => (
                  <Cards restaurantData={restaurant} />
            ))}
      </View>
   ) : null}
   <Button onPress={getData} title="Get Data" />
   <Divider style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />;
   <Button onPress={refreshData} title="Get Next 20 Restaurants" />
</View>
```

``

Comment: Is it possibility that, at some point of time, your `restaurantData` is null?. Could you try adding `restaurantData=== null && restaurantData.length > 0 ? ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a ';' at the end of this link. Try removing it to see if that resolves your problem. If think I would check to see if there's extra spaces around your code. Sometimes React native doesn't like trailing spaces or spaces around your tags.

```
<Divider style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />;
```

Comment: This worked. I cannot believe that I didnt see that. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: great! if you don't mind, please mark it as the answer :)